# How to block execution of function untill json return result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I am using Springer OpenAccess API with JS, they  provide their  data with many ways, one of them is  jsonp format. My code is shown below. What ever i do, i couldn't make it run synchronuously. Callback mechanism is good  solution but i want to  learn  how to run this function syncronously or how enable this function to behave syncronous.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
 SpringerAPI.prototype.getArticleInfo = function(doi){
    //create  url of article according to given doi...
    var url = this.endpoint.host+this.endpoint.method+''+'?q=doi:'+doi+'&api_key='+this.endpoint.apikey+"&callback=?";
    //get information about article...      
    //perform async request to the Springer API
    this.situation = true;
    var article;
    jQuery.ajax({
      method:'POST',
      url: url,
      dataType: 'JSON',
      cache: true,
     async: false, // to set local variable
     success: function(data)
     {
        article = FromSpringerToArticle(data,-1);
     }
    });


    return article;
};
```

Comment: Learning how to properly work with callbacks is much more useful than learning how to make an Ajax call synchronous. And JSONP cannot be synchronous because it is actually not Ajax. It's including a script tag pointing to the remote URL, which is never synchronous after the DOM loaded.

Comment: I know  how to use callbacks  but the requirement of our system is really different. If I couldn't find any solution, I want to Change Request from our Architect.

Comment: @ibrahimyilmaz: That (the CR) is your only option. JSON-P is asynchronous by nature, there's nothing whatsoever you can do to make your function wait until the JSON-P result arrives. Also, the architect should have designed it properly in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do synchronous JSONP because [jQuery doc says](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> #### async
>
> ...
> Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation...

You'll have to do an asyc operation and use callbacks.

Comment: Is there a any way to simulate  it? because i really need to do it :/

Comment: @ibrahimyilmaz: You shouldn't need to do it, and no, you can't simulate it.

Comment: @ibrahimyilmaz why? what's wrong with callbacks? if you are doing synchronous operations due to program design, then you've got some redesigning to do.

Comment: is there anyway to  wait  untill the response come ? I ask because i need to find a way :/

Comment: Synchronous operation means the browser will lock-up until the response is received -- not good. You can do a `while(article === undefined);` -- not good either.

Comment: callbacks are ok for me but our project mates say adapter have to seperate  its asynchronous nature :/

Comment: @SalmanA I tried it  but it doesnt work  properly in browser side :/

Comment: I think you can simulate it, but you should rethink your code in order to avoid this. You can use a global state var which will be set by the success callback. After calling your getArticleInfo you can call a function that simply controls the state of the variable and if it is not set, call itself with a setTimeout. When the variable is set you can continues with your code.

Comment: @ibrahimyilmaz You need to rethink your project, rather than make something do something it's not supposed to.

Comment: @Ibrahim: maybe you should start looking at deferred objects if integration is a problem. They provide a very flexible way to work with callbacks.

Comment: @ibrahimyilmaz: i changed my comment to compare `article` with `undefined`. Or do a `while(!article);`. Of course I think it is a very bad workaround and won't post it as an answer.

Comment: I have implemented  it  with callback mechanism but my project mates don't  accept it. I think they should implement their  synchronous implementation

Comment: @FelixKling What is deferred objects  could you give me any example about it?

Comment: @ibrahimyilmaz [they are objects that "promise"](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) to do something once there something interesting happens to them (like received replies, failed requests). By default, jQuery AJAX operations return deferreds.

Comment: @SalmanA: That sort of `while` loop just doesn't work in browser-based JavaScript, which is single-threaded (barring the use of [web workers](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/), which aren't relevant here) and thus because the while loop is hogging the thread, the callback that sets `article` is queued by never run. Besides which, very quickly indeed you'll get the "slow script" warning.

Comment: @ibrahimyilmaz: Sorry, I was posting from my phone. Joseph provided the right link and you will find many examples here on SO and the web.